# Error: React invalid hook call in document used to import handler

Tags: reactjs

I'm pretty new to javascript and react. I'm trying to call a handler for my project from another document, but I'm getting an error stating that said document has a **Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call**. I don't know why I'm having this problem as when I called similar handlers with similar constants and other information in previous documents I have never had this issue. I would really appreciate any advice or guidance on why I'm encountering this issue.
Thank you!

Extra.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {createDevolucion } from '../actions/devolucionActions';
import { DEVOLUCION_CREATE_RESET } from '../constants/devolucionConstants';

export default function Extra(props) {
  const order = useSelector((state) => state.order);
  const devolucionCreate = useSelector((state) => state.devolucionCreate);
  const {loading, success, error, devolucion } = devolucionCreate;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const placeDevolucionHandler = () => {
    dispatch(createDevolucion({ ...order, devolucionItems: order.ordertItems }));
   };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      props.history.push(`/devolucion/${devolucion._id}`);
      dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_CREATE_RESET });
    }
  }, [dispatch, devolucion, props.history, success]);
}
```

Document in which I am importing the handler

OrderHistoryScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { listOrderMine, detailsOrder } from '../actions/orderActions';
import placeDevolucionHandler from '../components/Extra';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import {createDevolucion } from '../actions/devolucionActions';
import { DEVOLUCION_CREATE_RESET } from '../constants/devolucionConstants';

export default function OrderHistoryScreen(props) {
  const orderId = props.match.params.id;
  const order = useSelector((state) => state.order);
  const orderMineList = useSelector((state) => state.orderMineList);
  const { loading, error, orders } = orderMineList;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listOrderMine());
    dispatch(detailsOrder(orderId));
  }, [dispatch, orderId]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Order History</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>ACTIONS</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {orders.map((order) => (
              <tr key={order._id}>
                
                <td>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={placeDevolucionHandler}
                  className="small"
                 // disabled={cart.cartItems.length === 0}
                >
                  Return Order
                </button>
                </td>
             
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```